# Automate variable declaration PHP

Tags: php, variables, declaration

I want to try and write a function to automate some of the legwork in checking/declaring a variable i.e.

```
function checkVariable($var)
{
if(!isset($var)||empty($var))
    {
    return '';
    }
else
    {
    return $var;
    }
}

$myvar = checkVariable($myvar);
```

obviously, this isn't going to work, because the variable doesn't exist prior to declaration and throws an error when you use it as an argument - sooooo, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: yes, but you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pass the variable by reference](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function checkVariable(&$var) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use

```
$myvar = (isset($myvar) && !empty($myvar)) ? $myvar : '';
```

But if you have to do this a lot, and you want to use a function, Gumbo's suggestion is right.